# React list, how does if else exactly work?

Tags: reactjs

so in my React App, I basically have three buttons. When the specific button is clicked, I want to update the clicked value to be true. I also want the rest of the items that weren't clicked to be false. Is there another way to target the elements that weren't clicked on? I got this solution, but am confused on how it exactly works. I thought that if the first if statement returned true, the else if wouldn't run? So can someone explain how these are both running?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // state
  state = {
    list: this.props.tabs,
    currentTabContent: '',
  };

  // event handlers
  onButtonClick(tab) {
    // ======THIS IS WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND========
    const newList = this.state.list.map((item) => {
      if (item === tab) {
        item.clicked = true;
      } else if (item !== tab) {
        item.clicked = false;
      }
      return item;
    });
    // ==============================================

    this.setState({
      currentTabContent: tab.content,
      list: newList,
    });
  }

  // helpers 

  renderButtons() {
    return this.props.tabs.map((tab, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          className={tab.clicked ? 'offset' : null}
          onClick={() => this.onButtonClick(tab)}
        >
          {tab.name}
        </button>
      </li>
    ));
  }

  renderContent() {
    return this.state.currentTabContent;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>{this.renderButtons()}</ul>
        <div className="display">{this.renderContent()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can replace the ```else if (item !== tab) {``` by ```else {```

Comment: Ok thanks, but can you explain how it works? The if statement returned true, so how is the else running? So basically, how is it setting the other values to be false?

Comment: It's because that condition is inside of a callback to map. That condition is being evaluated for every item in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding lies more in not quite understanding `if...else if` rather than anything to do with React. Let's take a look at your condition:

```js
      if (item === tab) {
        item.clicked = true;
      } else if (item !== tab) {
        item.clicked = false;
      }

      return item;
```

This function runs when the following is called by the button's click handler:

```js
() => this.onButtonClick(tab)
```

Where tab is a specific object corresponding to a specific button. You then map over `list` in state, which just appears to be the same list of tabs. For each object it checks if `tab === listItem` if that is true the stuff in the first block executes, that's why the correct button gets set to true. It then does not evaluate the second condition for that item, and just returns the item.

It then moves on to the other items, who will not be equal to tab, and they evaluate in the second condition, so they are marked as false for `clicked`.

There are some much more worrisome and larger issues in your code here that have more to do with you making comparisons between objects and the dataflow of your components, but those aren't the subject of your question here, I just wanted to warn you to look out for them in the future.

Comment: Cory, can you explain what you mean by there are larger issues for comparing objects to dataflow of my components? I'm still learning React so I might not know best practices

Comment: This will really take some further reading on your part to understand in depth. But to quickly sum it up, you shouldn't do direct comparisons between objects with `===` or really any built in equality operator unless you really know what that's doing under the hood. Here's an exerpt from MDN on equality to help you out:

"For any non-primitive objects x and y which have the same structure but are distinct objects themselves, all of the above forms will evaluate to false."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: The dataflow issue is seperate from that issue. What I'm referring to is that you take your props, make it state, and then change that state when you want to see the UI change. This is not a normal data flow in React. You should be passing down a function that changes that state in the parent that is handing down the props, and using that when you want to make changes in the child.

If that data has nothing to do with the parent, it should originate in the child.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'll look in the comparison objects you provided. I think I do know what you're saying about dataflow issue. In the future, I'll keep it in mind, but in my case I just have the topmost App (parent) only, as my index.js is the one passing the prop (<App tabs={tabs} />)

Comment: In that case, `App` should retrieve tabs directly, and set it in state. Almost always ina. React application, `index.js` only renders `App` and whatever provider components you might have.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll go ahead and move the tabs array inside my App.js and access it directly there without passing it as a prop from index.js then. Thanks a lot for your help Cory!